# Files load using different file paths on server and local

Tags: html, file, dreamweaver

When using css on my local Dreamweaver setup, I can only use the URL "./path/to/url" to load files. This is a problem, because on the server, I can only use the url "/path/to/url". Is there any reason this is happening?

Example :

`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./css/Defaults.css'>` on local,

`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/Defaults.css'>` on server.

This has been an ongoing problem for a while now and all previous answers found on google and stack overflow haven't worked.

Comment: You must configure your dreamviewer for url /path/to/url because this right.

Comment: But how do I do that?